# How to find missing angles in a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, quadrilateral

I have a quadrilateral **ABCD**, with diagonals **AC** and **BD**.
Given are four angles: **∠DAC** = 20°, **∠CAB** = 60°, **∠ABD** = 50°, and **∠DBC** = 30°.

[image: quadrilateral]

Those are the red angles in the above image.

I need to fill in all the other angles.  Most are trivial – the angles in blue – but how do I find **∠BDC** and **∠ACD**?  Their sum is 110, obviously, but I can't figure out how to find the individual angles.

**Edit:**  Note that the red angles are examples; I'm looking for a general solution given any values for these angles that form a convex quadrilateral.  (They do if **∠DAC** + **∠CAB** + **∠ABD** < 180° and **∠CAB** + **∠ABD** + **∠DBC** < 180; in that case you can draw triangles **ABD** and **ABC** and then quadrilateral **ABCD**.)

Comment: I'm not certain, but you might try extending the segments $AB,CD$ into lines which intersect at some point $E$. This adds a few angles, but one also has extra constraints e.g. $\angle EAD+\angle DAC+\angle CAB=180^\circ$. This may be enough to uniquely determine the missing angles.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @Semiclassical, but that doesn't seem to add new information.  All I can deduct is that **∠EAD** = 100, **∠DEA** = 60 - **∠ACD**, **∠ADE** = 20 + **∠ACD**, and therefore **∠BCD** = 110 - **∠ACD**, and we already knew that.

Comment: You're right, it really doesn't seem to help. One could also try the segments $AD,BC$  instead but I don't think this works any better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A numeric computation using the Laws
of [Sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)
and [Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) yields
$\angle ACD=30^{\circ}$ and $\angle BDC=80^{\circ}$.

Let the intersection of $AC$ and $BD$ be $E$ and, wlog, let $AB=1$.

\begin{align}
AD &= \frac{\sin 50^{\circ}}{\sin 50^{\circ}} = 1 \\
DE &= AD\frac{\sin 20^{\circ}}{\sin 110^{\circ}} = 0.36397023426620234 \\
BC &= \frac{\sin 60^{\circ}}{\sin 40^{\circ}} = 1.3472963553338608 \\
CE &= BC\frac{\sin 30^{\circ}}{\sin 110^{\circ}} = 0.71688141714205145 \\
CD &= \sqrt{CE^2+DE^2-2\times CE\times DE\times\cos 70^{\circ}} = 0.68404028665133743 \\
\angle ACD &= \arcsin\big(\frac{DE}{CD}\sin 70^{\circ}\big) = 29.999999999999996 \\
\angle BDC &= \arcsin\big(\frac{CE}{CD}\sin 70^{\circ}\big) = 79.999999999999986
\end{align}

Note that $\angle DAB = \angle ABC$. I am not sure how to use this to reach an elegant solution, but I am sure that a non-computation solution **will** use both this observation and $AB=AD$ in a non-trivial way.

Note also that, *post-factum*, $CD$ is tangent to the circumcircle of $\triangle ABD$ (because we computed that $\angle ACD=\angle BAD$).

Comment: Thanks, but can you elaborate?

Comment: Constructing the configuration in Geogebra validates these remarks, but this still requires explication.

Comment: Thanks, @sds, that's clear now.  I'm still hoping for a simpler solution, though – it feels like there should be one.  But if nobody comes up with something better, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: To elaborate on “it feels like there should be one”: all those sines, cosines, arcsines, squares and roots, and you end up with such round numbers.  Must be an easier way to get there.  (I may very well be mistaken.)

Comment: I'm satisfied now that there isn't a simple generic solution, so this is the best we can do.

Comment: For all future readers, there's a crucial mistake here. In the calculation of CD, it should be $cos70$, not $sin$. Took me a while to notice, and did not understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @MCFromScratch: thanks, I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 7):

I have four different and one general solution to this problem, I hope it will help you.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow! It's beautiful!

Comment: Those are some very nice geometric solutions!  The general solution isn't quite general enough, though: depending on the given angles, it might not be possible to extend lines AD and BC (or in your case BE and CD) to form a triangle.

Answer (score 4):

Use sine theorem for $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta ACD:$
$$\frac{AB}{\sin{40}}=\frac{AC}{\sin{80}}$$
$$\frac{AD}{\sin{ACD}}=\frac{AC}{\sin{(20+ACD)}}$$
Noting $AB=AD$, we can find $mACD=30, mBDC=80$.

Comment: Nice one!  It does work for the provided values, where indeed AB = AD (which I hadn't even noticed!), but unfortunately not for the generic case.

Comment: @farruhota How does $\frac{AD}{\sin{ACD}}=\frac{AC}{\sin{(20+ACD)}}$?

Comment: $\angle ADC = 180^\circ - (20+\angle ACD)$ and $\sin (180-\alpha)=\sin \alpha$

Answer (score 3):

Let $AC\cap DB=\{F\}$ and $L\in FC$ such that $\measuredangle ABL=60^{\circ}$.

Also, let $BL\cap AD=\{G\}$.

Since $\measuredangle DAB=\measuredangle CBA$, we see that $GC||AB$ and from here $GC=GL=LC$.

Now, since $\measuredangle DBA=\measuredangle ADB=50^{\circ}$, we obtain: $AL=AB=AD$, which says that $\measuredangle ADL=\frac{180^{\circ}-20^{\circ}}{2}=80^{\circ}$ and since $\measuredangle AGB=180^{\circ}-80^{\circ}-60^{\circ}=40^{\circ}$,

we obtain: $\measuredangle GLD=40^{\circ}$, which says that $DG=DL$.

But also $GC=CL$, which gives that $DC$ is a bisector of $\angle GCL$.

Thus, $\measuredangle DCA=\frac{1}{2}\cdot60^{\circ}=30^{\circ}$ and the rest is smooth.

Comment: Nice one!  Doesn't work generically, though.

Comment: @mscha For the general case there is law of sines.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you extend AD and BC to meet at E, this becomes the famous "Langley's adventitious angles" problem.  I have seen at least four proofs (other than non-proofs using numerical applications of the law of cosines) deriving angle ACD.  A good one is this:

Draw a line meeting AB at A, and meeting BC at F such that angle BAF is $20^\circ$. Thus AB = AF, and angle CAF is $40^\circ$.

Angle ABD and angle ADB are both $50^\circ$ so AD = AB, thus AF = AD.  In triangle AFD, sides AF and AD are equal and meet at an angle of $60^\circ$ so triangle AFD is equilateral and AF = FD.

Angle FBC = $80^\circ - 20^\circ - 20^\circ = 40^\circ$.  In triangle ACB, 
angle ACB is $180^\circ - 80^\circ - 60^\circ = 40^\circ$. So triangle AFC is isosceles and CF = AF.  Then CF = FD.

That shows that triangle CFD is isosceles and angles FCD and FDC are equal.  Angle CFD is $180^\circ$ minus angle AFD minus angle AFB which is  $180^\circ - 80^\circ - 60^\circ = 40^\circ$.  So angle FDC = angle FCD = $70^\circ$.

Finally since angle ACD plus angle ACF add to $70^\circ$,  angle is  $30^\circ$
(and angle ADC is $80^\circ$).

Comment: Thanks for the reference to "Langley's adventitious angles"; I didn't know that.  A quick google finds a lot to read about this!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need trig to solve this, it's completely doable by basic geometry, although you do have to draw a lot of stuff. Calculating those angles is actually a problem already online known as the "world's hardest easy problem" (problem 2)
https://www.duckware.com/tech/worldshardesteasygeometryproblem.html

There's a solution on the site, but I've shortly explained it alone.
(the quadrilateral from your problem is ABED on the picture, those sequences of 3 letters are supposed to be angles as I couldnt write them normally in paint)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMs7Y.jpg