# Solution explanation for finding the value of Angle $\theta$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, quadrilateral

Given the quadrilateral $ABGE$, angles $ABG$ and $EAB$ are both $80$ $degrees$, angle $GAB$ is $50$ $degrees$, and angle $EBA$ is $60$ $degrees$. Find the value of angle $\theta$.

[image]
I use the solution found in this link: [How to find missing angles in a quadrilateral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353677/how-to-find-missing-angles-in-a-quadrilateral)

Use sine theorem for $ΔABG$
and $ΔAGE$:

$\frac{AB}{\sin{40}}=\frac{AG}{\sin{80}}$

$\frac{AE}{\sin{AGE}}=\frac{AG}{\sin{(20+AGE)}}$

Noting $AB=AE$, we can find $mAGD=30$,$mBEG=80$.

How does $\frac{AE}{\sin{AGE}}=\frac{AG}{\sin{(20+AGE)}}$?

Comment: Related to the original problem of [the 80-80-20 triangle](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/index.shtml).

Comment: Related to [Langley's Adventitious Angles](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6942/89922).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find missing angles in a quadrilateral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353677/how-to-find-missing-angles-in-a-quadrilateral) - found using a [site search](/search?q=%5Bgeometry%5D+80+60+50).

Comment: In you update, which solution are you referring to? Where is $D$?

Comment: @peterwhy, thanks for the feedback, it's $E$.

Comment: [That answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2353740) says to use the sine theorem for $\triangle BEG$ to get$$\frac{BG}{\sin BEG} = \frac{BE}{\sin(20+BEG)}.$$